# SQLite: add DateTime and TimeSpan

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have a SQLite table that contains TimeFrames. Every TimeFrame has (at least) an EndTime and a Duration:

- EndTime represents the end DateTime of the time frame; In SQLite this is a string in format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
- Duration represents the TimeSpan of the time frame; In SQLite this is a double value representing the TotalSeconds of the Duration.

> Given some DateTime value dt, Query all TimeFrames that started before dt.

```
SELECT ...
FROM
WHERE dt < TimeFrame.EndTime - TimeFrame.Duration
```

To perform DateTime calculations, [SQLite has some Date and Time Functions.](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html). This helps me to perform the Where.

```
DateTime dt = ...
String dtText = DateTimeToSqlLiteFormat(dt);   // yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ttt
```

And SQLite:

```
Select ... From ...
Where dtText < DateTime( EndTime, "-nnn.nnnn seconds")
```

where `nnn.nnnn` is a string representation of the value of Duration.

So All I have to do is convert column Duration to `nnn.nnnn`. As Duration is already the double TotalSeconds of the TimeSpan it represents, I guess this won't be too hard.

But how?

Comment: [`DateTime( EndTime, -Duration || " seconds")`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/9eecb7/5700) ? `||` is string concatenate operator

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is still relevant, but you need to do it the other way around. Convert your EndDate to Unix time with `strftime('%s', EndTime)` (or julianday), then just subtract the duration from it:

```
Select ... From ...
Where dtText < strftime('%s', EndTime) - Duration
```

Comment: I ended up converting all datetimes and timespans to ticks. Way easier to do calculations.